# C++: Looking up a modified UINT_PTR in unordered_map<UINT_PTR,Object*>

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm working with an API in Windows that essentially callbacks with UINT_PTR (address of an object) and provides methods to get more information about these objects.

I have a collection where MyObject is my class that holds info I care about (not important to this question):

```
std::unordered_map<UINT_PTR,MyObject*> objectMap;
```

And I have a function that will be called multiple times.  In some cases the address provided by the API needs to be modified.  I'm unable to find any modified UINT_PTR in my collection.  For example:

```
void CallbackHandler::APICallback( UINT_PTR address )
{
    UINT_PTR collectionKey = address;

    if( SomeCondition() )
    {
        collectionKey -= 0x10;
    }

    if( objectMap.count( collectionKey ) == 1 )
    {
      // Write message to log, condition we care about occurred
    }
    else
    {
      // Do some info gathering and evaluation, possibly adding collectionKey to objectMap
    }
}
```

So for example, the first time the above function is called "0xFF4116A8" is added to the collection.   The second time the function is called, address="0xFF4116B8" and SomeCondition() happens to be true so we subtract 0x10 to get "0xFF4116A8" again.  However, objectMap.count("0xFF4116A8")==1 isn't true... but when I log the contents of the collection "0xFF4116A8" is indeed in there.

I suspect I'm making some sort of fundamental mistake trying to do arithmetic on a UINT_PTR or making some bad assumption about the behavior of unordered_map.  What mistake am I making here and what's the proper way to modify a UINT_PTR and then look it up in a collection?

Comment: if you substract 0x10 from an uint-ptr your adress will be decremented by 0x40 and not by 0x10

Comment: I have a question: why not just arrange things so the uintptr_t points to the instance of MyObject, rather than having the extra layer of indirection provided by the map?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Note that despite the name, UINT_PTR is a Windows type defined as unsigned __int64, and not a UINT *.  So the arithmetic is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies all!

It turns out the problem was elsewhere in the code.  The code was more like:

```
void CallbackHandler::APICallback( UINT_PTR address, SOME_TYPE_INFO typeInfo )
{
    UINT_PTR collectionKey = GetAddressForType( address, typeInfo );

    // Rest of the code the same...
```

Where GetAddressForType did:

```
UINT_PTR CallbackHandler::GetAddressForType( UINT_PTR address, SOME_TYPE_INFO typeInfo )
{
  UINT_PTR objectId = 0;

  switch( typeInfo )
  {
  case ELEMENT_TYPE_STRING:
    objectId = *(PUINT_PTR) address;
    break;
  case ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS:
    objectId = address;
    break;
  case ELEMENT_TYPE_I:    // fall through - intptr
  case ELEMENT_TYPE_U:    // fall through - uintptr
  case ELEMENT_TYPE_PTR:  // pointer
    objectId = *(UINT *) address; // This was the problem right here. Should be *(PUINT_PTR) cast.
    break;
  }

  return objectId;
}
```

Instead, I needed to use the same *(PUINT_PTR) cast as the string type.

Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Yes - one of the comments hints at the confusion around UINT_PTR (!= UINT *).  A lot of devs have tripped up over it, myself included.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot repro your example with this:

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct MyObject{};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::unordered_map<UINT_PTR,MyObject*> objectMap;
    UINT_PTR x = 0xFF4116A8;
    objectMap[x] = nullptr;
    UINT_PTR y = 0xFF4116B8;
    y -= 0x10;
    auto c = objectMap.count(y);    // c == 1
    return 0;
}
```

Are you on a 64-bit machine?  Is it possible that you're doing sign-extended pointer arithmetic in code you haven't provided?

Comment: I am on a 64 bit machine but I'm not doing any arithmetic besides the -= 0x10.